# Finding the equations of the lines and tangent to the circle

Tags: analytic-geometry

Find the equations of the lines through $(2,0)$ and tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.
I tried to solve this and I know the right answer but I just can't solve this. The right answer:  $\sqrt{3}y=x-2$ or $\sqrt{3}y=2-x$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

The equation of any line passing through $(2,0)$ can be written as $$\frac{y-0}{x-2}=m\iff y=m(x-2)$$ where $m$ is the gradient or slope

Now replace the value of $y$ in $x^2+y^2=1$ to form a Quadratic Equation in $x$

For tangency, the roots of the equation must be same i..e, the discriminant must be zero

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The equation of any line passing through $(2,0)$ can be written as $$\frac{y-0}{x-2}=m\iff mx-y-2m=0\  \ \ \ (1)$$ where $m$ is the gradient or slope

From [this](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII18.html), the distance of a tangent from the center of the respective circle equals to the radius

Now can you calculate the distance of $(1)$ from the center$(0,0)$?

Comment: @user146411, What's your Question?

Comment: The distance of 1 from the center (0,0) is 1?

Comment: @user146411, yes

Comment: @user146411, equate the radius($=1$) with the perpendicular distance

Comment: 1×0+1×0-1÷√1+1 ≫ -1÷√2 ≫ - √2÷2  I don't know what to do next