# line crossing through point (5, -2) tangent to the circle y^2 + x^2 = 9?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the points where lines crossing through the point (5, -2) would be tangent to the circle y^2 + x^2 = 9.

As a caveat however: this is supposed to be solvable using only college algebra. Every resource I've found thus far seems to reference calculus. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774250/finding-the-equations-of-the-lines-and-tangent-to-the-circle and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733953/equations-of-tangents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y = mx+b$ be the equation of the tangent line. Then since $(5,-2)$ is on this line, we know that $-2 = 5m + b$ so that $\boxed{b = -2 - 5m}$.

Now consider the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
x^2 + y^2 = 9 \\
y = mx + b
\end{cases}$$
Substituting, we find that:
\begin{align*}
x^2 + (mx+b)^2 &= 9 \\
x^2 + (m^2x^2 + 2mbx + b^2) &= 9 \\
(1 + m^2)x^2 + (2mb)x + (b^2 - 9) &= 0
\end{align*}
But since the line is **tangent**, we know that this system must have exactly one intersection point so that the discriminant of the above quadratic equation must be zero. Thus:
\begin{align*}
(2mb)^2 - 4(1+m^2)(b^2 - 9) &= 0 \\
4m^2b^2 - 4b^2 + 36 - 4m^2b^2 + 36m^2 &= 0 \\
9m^2 - b^2 + 9 &= 0 \\
9m^2 - (-2-5m)^2 + 9 &= 0 \\
9m^2 - (4 + 20m + 25m^2) + 9 &= 0 \\
-16m^2 - 20m + 5 &= 0 \\
m &= \frac{-(-20) \pm \sqrt{(-20)^2 - 4(-16)(5)}}{2(-16)} \\
m &= \frac{-5 \pm 3\sqrt 5}{8}
\end{align*}

Thus, the equations of the two tangent lines are:
$$\begin{cases}
y = \left(\dfrac{-5 - 3\sqrt 5}{8} \right)x -2 - 5\left(\dfrac{-5 - 3\sqrt 5}{8} \right) \\
y = \left(\dfrac{-5 + 3\sqrt 5}{8} \right)x -2 - 5\left(\dfrac{-5 + 3\sqrt 5}{8} \right)
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $D$ be the point where the tangent line intersects the circle, let $P$ be the point $(5,-2)$ and let $O$ be the origin of the plane. The triangle $ODP$ is a right angled triangle with the right angle at $D$. You know how far away $D$ is from $O$ and you know how far away $P$ is from $O$. You can do some basic trigonometry with this information.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.
The tangent line at (5,-2) is perpendicular to the radius passing through (5,-2)