# How to find points of tangency

Tags: calculus

I need to find the points of tangency on a circle (x^2+y^2=100) and a line y=5x+b the only thing I know about b is that it is negative. This line runs parallel to the line y=5x+7. I need to find the points of tangency between the line y=5x+b and the circle.

Comment: What's the derivative of the equation representing a circle? What's the derivative of your line?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254073/the-line-y-mxc-is-a-tangent-to-x2y2-a2-if  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774250/finding-the-equations-of-the-lines-and-tangent-to-the-circle

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

solve the equation $$(5x+b)^2+x^2-100=0$$ and set the discriminatin equal to Zero to find $b$

Comment: Are you saying to set x = 0? that would mean b= 10 which is impossible based on our initial conditions

Comment: no compute the discriminatin and set it equal to Zero and compute $b$

Comment: this is $-b^2+2600=0$

Answer (score 0):

The distance from the center to the line is
$$\frac {-b}{\sqrt {26}}=10$$

Answer (score 0):

The tangent will be perpendicular to the radius  $y = -\frac 15 x.$

This line intersects the circle.

$x^2 + (-\frac 15 x)^2 = 100\\
\frac {26}{25} x^2  = 100\\
x = \pm 50\frac {\sqrt {26}}{26},y = \mp 10 \frac{\sqrt {26}}{26}$

There are two points of tangency.

$(y+10\frac {\sqrt{26}}{26}) = 5(x-50\frac {\sqrt{26}}{26})\\
(y-10\frac {\sqrt{26}}{26}) = 5(x+50\frac {\sqrt{26}}{26})$

Comment: The line y=5x+b can't have two points of tangency, the definition of tangent is that it touches at one point.

Comment: Sure it can.  For two different values of $b, y = 5x + b_1$ and $y = 5x + b_2$ are parallel lines and each can be tangent to opposite sides of the circle.

Comment: ok that makes sense, still if you solve for x and y you get, (9.8, -1.96) those aren't the correct answers.

Comment: @ianlindell Those are the correct coordinates of the tangent point for the problem as you’ve posed it here. If that’s not what your answer key has, then it’s either wrong (it happens), or you’ve misinterpreted the question.

Comment: I would say $(25 \frac {\sqrt {26}}{13}, -5\frac {\sqrt{26}}{13}) \ne (9.8, -1.96)$  It is close, but it is not exact