# Find tangent line to curve $(X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 =5$

Tags: circles, tangent-line

> i was given $$(X-1)^2+(Y+1)^2 =5$$, it said when $k$ maximum, this line $X+2Y-k=0$ will tangent the circle.
>
> i was asked to find $k$.
>
> Previous section we denoted $k$ for $\log_2 xy^2$ and $X=\log_2 x; Y=\log_2 y$

I used $$y=mx + r\sqrt{m^2+1}$$ and i get $2Y + X - 5 $. But the answer is $k=4$, what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get family of tangents:
$$y+1=m(x-1)\pm \sqrt{5} \sqrt{1+m^2}~~~~(1),$$
where $m$ is a real number.
So if $x+2y-k=0$ touches the given circle then perpendicular on it from the center $(1,-1)$ should equal the radius:
$$|\frac{1-2-k}{\sqrt{5}}|=\sqrt{5} \implies (1+k)^2=25 \implies k=4,-6.$$
One may also use (1) to get to this answer by re-writing $x+2y-k$ as
$$x-1+2(y+1)-1-k \implies (y+1)=-\frac{1}{2}(x-1)+(1+k)/2$$
This means $m=-1/2$ so the intercept
$$(1+k)/2 =\pm \sqrt{5} \sqrt{1+m^2}$$

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Accept answer in 10 minutes

Comment: @Lifeforbetter, See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774250/finding-the-equations-of-the-lines-and-tangent-to-the-circle and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254073/the-line-y-mxc-is-a-tangent-to-x2y2-a2-if

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact the distance of any tangent from the center is equal to the radius of the circle

So, $$\sqrt5=\dfrac{|1+2-k|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}$$

Comment: Oh. Right. Nice idea. Thanks